# Discover the origin of a page view: clicks from Menu, Banner, etc

Tags: google-analytics

I need to discover the origin of a page view: click from Menu, Banner, etc. For exemple:

```
Page 1 - 12 hits
----------------
Menu   - 6 hits
Banner - 4 hits
Other  - 2 hits
```

.

```
Page 2 - 15 hits
----------------
Menu   - 7 hits
Banner - 5 hits
Other  - 3 hits
```

How can I track the origin and build a report like this? I search and find a lot of things using Google Analytics, but can't figure out how to do it.

**EDIT:**

I tried to use the *trackEvent* on the items I want to track, but I can figure out how to build the report with this events.

```
$('#menu').find('a').click(function()
{
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Menu', 'click']);
}
$('.banner').find('a').click(function()
{
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Banner', 'click']);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events are good for tracking totals of.. ermmm.. 'events'. That is, anything that isn't a pageview that you want to keep a track of. You'll find the reports in *Content / Events*. As such, I think your code looks fine

However, in your question you say:

> I need to discover the origin of a page view

That sounds to me like you want to track the what caused a user to reach a particular page, so you can determine what are your best traffic drivers for that area. To do this, you're better off using campaign code on the URLs.

So, to link to page1.html, you might have previously had:

```
<a href="./page1.html">page 1</a>
```

add to this campaign tracking like this:

```
<a href="./page1.html?utm_source=website.com&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=ads">page 1</a>
```

The arguments for the source etc are arbitrary, you might benefit from taking a look at the [URL Builder here](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1007028&answer=1033867). You'll then be able to see reports for your campaigns in a few ways:

1. Go to *Content / Site Content* and use the *Pages* or *Content Drilldown* reports and dd in a secondary dimension showing your campaign name, medium or source.
2. Go to *Traffic Sources / Sources / Campaigns* to view all of your campaign traffic. See which ones are driving the most etc.
3. You could create an *Advanced Segment* to only include specific campaigns information and hence, show you only the traffic generated by that campaign.

see also: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCampaigns.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="./index.html" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'mainmenu', 'home'])">home</a>
<a href="./contact.html" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'mainmenu', 'contact'])">contact</a>
```

Wait at least 24hours before the data will apear.
Then the results will show in GA under Content > Events

Then you can see per "category" how many clicks there where made to home or contact for example.

Comment: I already try this, but... theres is no report to view what events reach the page.

Comment: With this way we can see how many people click "Main Menu" from "Home Page". I want to see how many people reach "Page1" from "Main Menu".

Comment: Go to Audience > Visitors Flow > Change Country/Territory to Event Action or Event Label, and add the pushed event name in the expression field.

That way you should see the Visitors Flow with your data.